# How do I capture a proof of a file downloaded through https?

Tags: ssl, https

Is there any way that I can create a proof of a file downloaded using https? With proof I mean a cryptographic record of some sort that links the contents of a file to a site at a certain time. If I understand TLS correctly, the server certificate is only used as a basis to establish a session key that is known to both parties, so each request is not signed but just encrypted for transfer. Any ideas if this can be done and if so how?

Comment: I am sorry but based on your question it is not clear what you want to achieve. What do you want to prove who is the party you want to present this prove?

Comment: I realize the question was a bit unclear, but the links shared by Steffen does address my intended use; i.e. proving to a third party that a specific file (which is kept for reference after download) was indeed available at a given site at a given time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTTPS the certificate is only used for authentication and with the obsolete RSA key exchange also for key exchange. Application data are only protected against modification by some man in the middle but they are not signed by the sender. While a HTTP server could be explicitly implemented to sign and timestamp the content, one can not enforce such operation against an arbitrary existing server.

For more see

- [Where in a TLS connection can I get the signature of the content sent by the server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95213/where-in-a-tls-connection-can-i-get-the-signature-of-the-content-sent-by-the-ser)
- [Why does HTTPS not support non-repudiation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242482/why-does-https-not-support-non-repudiation)
- [How to prove some server sent some file over HTTPS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/143375/how-to-prove-some-server-sent-some-file-over-https)
- [Proving authenticity of data accessed over TLS by an untrusted third party](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/proving-authenticity-of-data-accessed-over-tls-by-an-untrusted-third-party)

Comment: Thanks Steffen Ullrich - great answer and very relevant links that completely addressed my question!